# Can I expect another Xcode 13.2 update beyond 13.2.1 that would support iOS 15.4?

Tags: macos, ios, xcode, upgrade

Where can I find a roadmap for Xcode to know if Apple intends to provide another 13.2 update?

I foolishly upgraded my iPhone to iOS 15.4.1 without first checking if Xcode 13.2.1 supports it. I can't upgrade Xcode to 13.3 without first upgrading macOS to 12. I've heard some horrible problems (memory management) exist for that release and I'm wanting to wait a bit longer before upgrading from macOS 11.6.5. And there's no telling what other programs (e.g. VMware Fusion) I might have to upgrade after a macOS upgrade.

Comment: My understanding is that memory management has been cleaned up in the latest macOS releases, so I would go ahead an upgrade. Furthermore, some security patches aren't present in previous OS versions.

Comment: For what it's worth, macOS Monterey has overall been much better than Big Sur ever was, but if you have critical apps or utilities, it's worth reviewing what versions might require an update.

Comment: As a sidenote.. you can add new iOS version support for older xcode versions.
https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport  I am still rocking xcode 13.0 while debugging iOS 16 beta already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely there will be another version of Xcode 13.2 that supports both macOS 11.6.5 and iOS 15.4.1.

If there is another update, such as a security update (which typically doesn't happen, but plausibly could), it wouldn't change compatibility.